# sitemap.xml approach on non-indexed site

Tags: seo, sitemap, search-engine-indexing, noindex

On a site that has a *robots.txt* file that disallows all crawling...

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

...does it matter what the *sitemap.xml* content is? Is it better, or does it make a difference at all, if requests to *sitemap.xml* return a 404, a 403, or an empty XML file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156184?hl=en

> Sitemaps are a way to tell Google about pages on your site we might
>   not otherwise discover.

This means you don't need a sitemap if you don't want Google to discover anything. Having a sitemap won't do anything so I wouldn't make one at all.

Comment: Yep, just to add further clarification to this answer. A sitemap is only required if a crawler would have difficulty crawling the website - typically these can either be poorly constructed websites or websites that possess a deep and complex level of hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

In contrast to robots.txt, the sitemap doesn’t have a fixed name/location.

You could name it "s" instead of "sitemap.xml". And it doesn’t have to be placed in the host root. See http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#location.

So it’s likely that search engines wouldn’t try to guess if there is a sitemap (or, if they would try it, they can’t expect to find something). There are [various ways to inform search engines about your sitemap location](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#informing).